# Drools: using rule "exists" for a Map(Scala)

Tags: scala, drools

I have a class "Records" which has a Map[String,Double](Scala) attribute "payOrders" and I want to find out whether the map contains value larger than 50. The rule I wrote is like this:

```
rule "user1"
   dialect "mvel"
   no-loop
   when
      $user:Records($pay:payOrders.values)
      exists(Number(doubleValue > 50) from $pay)
   then
      System.out.println("user1")
end
```

The problem is there is no error but the rule doesn't work! No outputs. 
Then, I tried to print `$pay`. The output is `$pay:MapLike(300.0)`. First I thought drools can't analyze this type, so I revised `$user:Records($pay:payOrders.values)` to `$user:Records($pay:payOrders.values.toList)`. But it still prints nothing. It seems that once I added the exists line, the rule just don't work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Works for me, using 5.5.0. - If you omit the "exists(...)", can you print $pay in the then part?

Comment: The rule still dosen't work after I changed my version. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then it might be some Scala/Java/Drools incompatibility. Try the Drools user list.